# model serialization - what is ".pk" format?

Tags: serialisation

I encountered a piece of pytorch code where the trained model is saved with  `.pk`. I often see pytorch models being saved as `.pth` or `.pt`. What is `.pk` format and how is it different from `.pth` or `.pt`?

Btw, the following parameters and weights are saved under the `.pk` file:

```
save_dict = {
        "encoderOpts": encoderOpts,
        "classifierOpts": classifierOpts,
        "dataOpts": dataOpts,
        "encoderState": encoder_state_dict,
        "classifierState": classifier_state_dict,
    }
```

Many thanks in advance!